# Netbeans not compatible with maven 3.1.1, ignores maven-distributed dependency

Tags: java, android, maven, netbeans, apk

Maven projects using apk (android-maven-plugin 3.8.2) packaging are displayed as "unloadable" in Netbeans 7.4 (using maven 3.1.1) because Netbeans obviously fails to find the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.sisu</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.sisu.plexus</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.0.M5</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>/opt/maven/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.0.0.M5.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

As you can see, I already tried to convince Netbeans to look for it at the correct place, but it seems to insist on finding it inside the m2 local repository and fails to do so because maven silently skips the jar download. Command line execution of maven is just fine.

Anyone knowing a temporary fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is sufficient to switch to Netbeans' internal maven (which is version 3.0.5 and incompatible with android-maven-plugin) and resolve the project issues, because the old maven version downloads the dependency into the local repo. After the download, switch back to maven 3.1.1+ and all seems ok.